# Why one thing works and another thing doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

Why does following code1 works and code2 doesn't?

Code1:

```
#Read from a file

readMe = open('WriteToFile.txt', 'r').read() 
print( readMe)

splitMe = readMe.split('\n')

print(splitMe)
```

Code 2:

```
#Read from a file

readMe = open('WriteToFile.txt', 'r')
print( readMe.read())

splitMe = readMe.read().split('\n')

print(splitMe)
```

I am getting the following output for code2:
[image]

while I want the output to be like code1 : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `read()` to go through a file, the file "pointer" (kinda like cursor) stays at the end of the file, and calling `read()` again does nothing since you're already at the end (and there's nothing to read). You need to move the pointer to the beginning of the file with `file.seek(0)`.

However, it's better to just read it once to a string and use that:

```
readMe = open('WriteToFile.txt', 'r')
content = readMe.read()

print( content)

splitMe = content.split('\n')

print(splitMe)
```

Even better is to use the `with` statement, which automatically closes the file for you:

```
with open('WriteToFile.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
print(content)
lines = content.split('\n')
print(lines)
```

Although, if your end goal is to just get the lines, you can use `readlines()`:

```
with open('WriteToFile.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
print(lines)
```